# Does Visual Studio Code support Ivy as a dependency management for Java projects?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, visual-studio-code, ivy

Our company has legacy projects built with Spring MVC (not boot) and using Ivy for dependency management, with repos using Artifactory. 
I cannot find any tutorials or support for Ivy / Ant, but rather only Maven type projects.

Has anyone got VS Code to place nice with a projects using Ivy?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can get it to work. You can use ivy via Apache Ant and there's a [plugin for Apache Ant available for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nickheap.vscode-ant).

Here is a sample Ant target that uses Ivy-defined targets to resolve dependencies.

```xml
<!--override the common resolve task to use Ivy configuration here-->
<target name="resolve" description="--> resolve and retrieve jar dependencies with ivy for all configurations.">
    <mkdir dir="${lib.dir}" />
    <!-- not usually necessary, ivy creates the directory IF there are dependencies -->

    <!-- the call to resolve is not mandatory, retrieve makes an implicit call if we don't -->
    <ivy:resolve file="${ivy.file}" conf="*" />

    <ivy:retrieve pattern="${lib.dir}/[conf]/[organisation]/[module]/[type]s/[artifact].[ext]" conf="*" />
</target>
```

Comment: it does not work in multiroot workspaces, right? get an error message "workspace does not have a build.xml"

Comment: This looks like it would ivy:resolve into a lib directory of the project. Ok. Good. However, will vscode then use that local library to resolve the import statements in the java sources loaded into the editors? That's the hard part, not just getting an ant ivy task to do the resolve.